# React Object Entries Renders Nothing

Tags: reactjs

So I have this code:

```
class LatestRecipes extends Component
{
  render()
  {
     return(
      <div>
        <ul>
        {
          Object.entries(this.props.latestRecipes).forEach(([key, recipe]) => 
            <li key={key}>
              <div key={key}>
                <Link to={{pathname: '/recipe/' + recipe.Name, state: { recipe: recipe, key: key }}}>{recipe.Name}</Link>    
              </div>
            </li>
        )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
   }
}
```

But my React App doesn't render any *li* elements.

This is my `this.props.latestRecipes` right now:

```
-LOyADRLntFBWyj1TtGx: {Description: "Description", Ingredients: Array(1), Name: "Name"}
-LOyBKQJcAsR0YfHAjrZ: {Description: "Description", Ingredients: Array(1), Name: "Name"}
```

What I want is beeing able to send in both `key` (-LOyADRLntFBWyj1TtGx) and the `recipe` to the Recipe component. And render the Recipe details in the `li` element

No errors, no nothing and if I console log it I get the exact results that I'm looking for.

Comment: You don't need the `key` prop in the inner `div`. The `key` on React is to keep track of the elements of an array and minimize re-rendering. It does not matter for the child elements (unless they are an array themselves).

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly new to this. Will remember that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `map` instead of a `forEach`.

The `Array.forEach` function does not return an array of elements (it returns `undefined` according to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), as the `map` returns a new array, based on the elements of the array being mapped.

For example:

```
const timesTwo = [1, 2, 3].map(e => e * 2);
console.log(timesTwo); // output: [2, 4, 6]
```

The same does not work for `forEach`. you would have to do it like this:

```
const timesTwo = [];
[1, 2, 3].forEach(e => {
  timesTwo.push(e * 2);
});
console.log(timesTwo); // output: [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: that's not dumb. Easy to miss. Everyone does that once in a while!